# How do I make bar-codes appear adjacent to each-other as one linear sequence?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, t4

When placing barcode_128 functions next to each-other I see it outputted in rows. How can this be changed so that the bar-codes appear next to each-other as one linear sequence?

```
        <b style="white-space: nowrap;">[% ordhead.custponum %][% ordhead.nosinum %][% order.ordernum %]-[% ordhead.nosinum %]</b>
                    [% END %]

        [% ordhead.custponum.barcode_128( 40,1 ) %][% ordhead.nosinum.barcode_128( 40,1 ) %][% order.ordernum.barcode_128( 40,1 ) %]-[% ordhead.nosinum.barcode_128( 40,1 ) %]
```

Comment: What are you targetting: Winforms, WPF, ASP..? 
YOU should __always__ TAG your questions correctly so one can see it on the questions page!

Comment: The file format is .tt which I believe is Visual Studio. (I'm new to this so hopefully this clarifies things?)

Comment: Um, `.tt` usually is a TrueType font but probabnly not here, as Lars notes.. I was asking about your application; is it ASP or what?

Comment: @TaW Maybe this: [What is the '.tt' extension](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34621378/719186)

Comment: Ah, quite right!